# if a class in its constructor contains an int,, and an array.. how can i use the array in another class.?

Tags: java

```
class C()
{
  num =4;
  int[] a = new int[5];
}
```

in a new class if i called   C

```
C c1 = new C();
```

how can i use array a..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually not recommended to allow direct access to variables from different classes. What you should do is something like this:

```
public class C
{
   private int num = 4;
   private int[] a = new int[5];

   public int[] geta()
   {
       int[] arr = new int[a.length];
       System.arraycopy(a, arr, 0, a.length)
       return arr;
   }
}

public class Foo
{
   .
   .
   .
   C c = new C();
   int[] nums = c.geta();
}
```

[This](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090301083220AAB5iUL) post should help you understand better getters and setters

Edit: Thanks for the comment rsp.

Comment: Note that if `getA()` does not return a copy of `a`, callers of `getA()` can now change elements of `a` in `c`. Most of the time this is not what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Provide an accessor (getter) method to your class and let it make a defensive copy of the array.

```
public int[] getA(){
    return Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
}
```

Now the other class can do `c.getA()` to get a copy of the array (thus we protect the original array from modification).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using it from the same package, then just int[] arr = c.a; Otherwise you'll have to make C.a field public.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:
Make it public.

The hard way: (and more professional)
Make it private and provide a public property.

```
C c1 = new C();
c1.a[0] = 3;
// So on...
```

Comment: Property? are you confusing Java and C#?

Comment: No, I call it that since it plays the same role.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of explanation: default access to class fields is package access. Default access means that no access modifiers are used (public, private, ..).

For more info: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

**A.**

```
c1.a
```

Only for those classes who belong to the same package level.

Answer (score 0):

As you've defined int[] a as a local variable within the constructor, it cannot be accessed by any other class, or indeed another function of the same class. Perhaps your intent is to make it a member variable, i.e.

```
public class C
{
  public int[] a;
  public int num;

  public C()
  {
    a=new int[5];
    num=42;
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere you could write:

```
C c=new C();
if (c.num==37) ... etc ...
```

Arguably you might want getters and setters instead of making the variables public, as some others have noted. I won't go into the relative merits of public members versus private members with public getters here.